# Writing to files on system drive C: without admin rights in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, admin-rights

I am trying to write Memo text to a .txt file in Delphi XE3, in Windows 8, but for some reason when I run the program in the IDE it works (the temp .exe is on my D: drive) but when I copy my program to C:\Myprogram.exe it gives error "Access denied" so i cant write anywhere on C:\

I already tried making a manifest and that did not work.

P.S.: I don't want to run my program as an administrator and when I do run as admin it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're not an administrator, you cannot write in certain places. That is to protect you (or your users) and it's a rule you cannot circumvent without disabling UAC, which you should't rely on (if it's possible at all in Windows 8).

Pick a location you *can* write to, for instance a Documents folder or another [special folder](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/a/SHGetFolderPath.htm) for storing application data.

Comment: Oh sorry i feel stupid now because i tried everywhere but a documents folder, well it works its just a pity i cant write to program files.

Comment: Yeah, many people feel that way, but it's for the best, really. :)

Comment: You'd better really avoid using global variables and global files until absolutely inevitable and necessary.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: Yes, Program Files and Application Data have been separated for this reason, specifically to prevent malicious programs from writing to the Program Files in attempt to alter some software, etc.